# Android - YouTube AdSense does not render on an Android WebView

Tags: javascript, android, youtube, android-webview

I have a WebView in Android, and most things render fine. My Youtube videos render fine, but the ads on them do not show up.  I checked and JavaScript is enabled. So I am not sure why the ads do not render.

Here is the code that I use:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);   
    webview = new WebView(this);
    setContentView(webview);

    webview.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(false);
    webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webview.setInitialScale(1);
    webview.getSettings().setPluginState(PluginState.ON);

    WebSettings webSettings = webview.getSettings();

    webSettings.setLoadsImagesAutomatically(true);
    webSettings.setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
    webSettings.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);   
    webSettings.setUseWideViewPort(true);

    webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            view.loadUrl(url);              
            return false;
        }
    });        


    webview.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient(){});

    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webSettings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
    webSettings.setAppCacheEnabled(true);
    webSettings.setAppCachePath(getApplicationContext().getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath() + "/cache");
    webSettings.setDatabaseEnabled(true);
    webSettings.setDatabasePath(getApplicationContext().getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath() + "/databases");

    webview.loadUrl("http://javatester.org/javascript.html");           
}
```

Would anyone know why the AdSense ads do not render, and how I can make it render?

Thanks!

Comment: are they supposed to, according to google?

Comment: Are you sure the javascript you are using is supported by mobile devices?